# Rails format result when grouping across multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, format

I'm trying to add support for multiple groups in my vehicles API. Currently we only support grouping by a single column like this.

```
Vehicle.group(:fuel_type).count
```

Which gives me a result like this:

```
{
  "Petrol": 78,
  "Diesel": 22
}
```

When I add multiple groups like this:

```
Vehicle.group(:fuel_type, :registration_status).count
```

I get the following result, which isn't as pretty in an API response. Also it's missing the combination Petrol and Exported since the count is 0.

```
{
  "['Diesel', 'Scrapped']": 5,
  "['Petrol', 'Registered']": 6,
  "['Petrol', 'Scrapped']": 30,
  "['Diesel', 'Registered']": 1,
  "['Diesel', 'Deregistered']": 11,
  "['Petrol', 'Deregistered']": 42,
  "['Diesel', 'Exported']": 5
}
```

I would like it to be formatted like this instead:

```
{
  "Diesel": {
    "Scrapped": 5,
    "Registered": 1,
    "Deregistered": 11,
    "Exported": 5
  },
  "Petrol": {
    "Scrapped": 30,
    "Registered": 6,
    "Deregistered": 42,
    "Exported: 0
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like to support n nested groups, where every combination is displayed in every layer eg. even though there are no exported petrol cars, then it should still be included in the response with a count of 0.

Comment: What you're looking to do here is way beyond the scope of what `ActiveRecord::Calculations` does which is just trivial aggregations and this ins't something that rails will magically do for you. Grouping will give you an row for each group with the aggregate for that group - `#count` is just barely smart enough to turn a simple result into a hash.

Answer (score 1):

I actually posted my question to openAI's ChatGPT and got a working implementation. Here is the snippet incase anyone has a similar issue:

```
def handle_hash(query)
  return query unless query.is_a?(Hash)
  result = {}

  query.each do |key, value|
    if key.is_a?(String)
      result[key] = value
    else
      current = result
      key[0...-1].each do |element|
        current[element] ||= {}
        current = current[element]
      end
      current[key[-1]] = value
    end
  end

  result
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: Didn't know that! Thanks - I'll remove the answer.